# One suite of tests for different implementations of a protocol

Tags: acceptance-testing

We have a *logging protocol* that defines how output of *logging libraries* should look like, e.g.:

- each line should be a JSON
- each line should not exceed 1MB

There are multiple implementation of this logging protocol, i.e, logging libraries written in different languages (Java, Python, etc.). I would like to create one set of tests that I can run against any logging library to verify it complies to the logging protocol. I don't want authors of a new library to port existing test. Instead, I want them to reuse existing tests.

The are already known solutions to that like [Reactive Streams Test Compatibility Kit](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/tree/master/tck), but they work for implementations in the same language (or at least for JVM-languages). In my case implemtations can be of different languages.

How can I make tests language independent?

**Initial idea**

1. My first idea is based on assumption that logging libraries always take one or two arguments:

   ```
   logging.error("Serious problem occurred", exception)
   ```

   and log output to a log file

   ```
   { level: "error", message: "Serious problem occurred", stacktrace: "....."}
   ```
2. The test harness would pass some string to the testing library and verify the output.
3. The test harness would communicate with a logging library through a pipeline, so the only thing that the creator of the library need to provide is a wrapper for handling communication with a test harness (through pipeline).

Is there a better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: How does the infrastructure look like which runs the test? And about how many languages/libs are you really talking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I should've propably asked what are the limitations of my solutions. Also, I don't want to re-invent wheel: I am sure that the idea of standard/protocol and verifier for implementations of this protocol is quite a generic problem, e.g., XML verifiers, TCK for Reactive Streams. So I am looking for similar solutions to learn from.

Comment: @DocBrown So far, only three libraries, in: Java, Python, and node.js. Tests are run on Jenkins, but I haven't thought about test runner yet. I thought that my test harness would 1) generate input, 2) call underlying library through some wrapper, 3) receive output.

Comment: You might be interested in the architecture of Android's (AOSP's) Compatibility and Vendor Test Suites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language independet tests are entirely possible, but the problem is that you need to define a language-agnostic format for these test cases, and write parsers/test drivers for this format in each language. It could happen that such a test driver would end up being more complicated than the protocol you are testing.

Such language-independent tests may use [Cucumber-style specifications](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference), an ad-hoc format, or a markup language like XML or YAML.

In your case, a simple YAML test case might look like:

```
---
name: Simple error
error: Serious problem occurred
output:
  json:
    level: error
    message: Serious problem occurred
...
```

Now unfortunately this test case is extremely weak because the input and expected output are very similar. But it's a start.

You will also have difficulty abstracting over language-specific properties, such as:

- the format of stack traces (which some languages like C or C++ don't have in a standardized fashion)
- injecting and asserting language-specific objects such as exception objects (which some languages like C and to some degree C++ and Perl don't have)

Instead of writing language-agnostic test cases, it may be far easier to write a short but clear specification of your protocol. Then, all implementations can be (manually) reviewed for conformance. An implementation may of course still have individual test cases.